# Can I use JPA by specifing the database during runtime?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jndi

I use MySQL on my production server, where every customer has its own database and its own database user to connect to his database. Each database has the exact same structure. Customers (and therefore databases) are added during the lifetime of the server.

Currently I establish a MySQL database connection with the class `java.sql.DriverManager`, which works just fine. The databases url, user, password and driver name are stored in several properties-files. The servlet reads the properties-file from the current customer and creates the `java.sql.Connection` with the `java.sql.DriverManager`.

I really want to use the JPA, but as far as I know the JPA can only be used by explicitly specifing the databases in the configuration of the webcontainer (in my case Tomcat). But that means, when a new customer registers on my platform, I have to add the new database to the webcontainer-configuration and restart the webcontainer, which does not sound like a good idea.

Is there a way to use the JPA and still have the flexibility to add new databases during the lifetime of the webcontainer?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should not use `DriverManager` inside a web application. Use a data source (with a connection pool) instead.

Comment: But as far as I understand, when I use the JNDI I run into the same problem as described above. I have to explicitly specify the databases in the configuration of the webcontainer.

Comment: Hibernate allows you to configure it in code, and so does for example spring-jpa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do what you ask, but the demon is in the details.

I would call it JPA Multitenancy, and [here](https://www.tomas-dvorak.cz/posts/jpa-multitenancy/) is an interesting article provided by a random search, that proposes a valid method using CDI. I will start with a more generic approach, taking into account the fact that you also require runtime additions of new tenants.

Note also that Hibernate offers [native solutions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy) for multitenancy. I do not know which JPA provider you are using, but I would guess others have similar features.

#### Basics

It has to be done using separate, tenant-specific `EntityManagerFactory` instances. The exact DB connection URL can be given by the map passed to `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()`. E.g., given that `META-INF/persistence.xml` exists, the following code applies:

```
HashMap props = new HashMap();
props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", /* tenant-specific JDBC URL*/);
EntityManagerFactory tenantSpecificEntityManagerFactory =
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("name-of-persistence-unit-from-persistence.xml", props);
```

The `props` generally override any properties specified in `persistence.xml`. Probably overriding only the JDBC URL is enough, maybe you will need to override user/password or other things as well. From that point on, you can get the tenant-specific persistence context and work with it:

```
EntityManager tenantSpecificEm = tenantSpecificEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

#### Catch: Efficiency

You could execute the code above every time you need a tenant-specific `EntityManager` (and then close the factory as well). But it would be *grossly inefficient* for the following reasons:

1. Creating the `EntityManagerFactory` anew with each request is slow
2. Creating the DB connection anew with each request is even slower

To address these issues you will need to:

1. Cache the `EntityManagerFactory` instances
2. Use connection pooling somehow

#### Caching the `EntityManagerFactory` instances

I assume there is a robust mechanism to relate each request with the appropriate tenant. Additionally you will need an application-scoped `Map` of tenant name to the corresponding `EntityManagerFactory` instance. How this is stored and used depends on the application, e.g. is there any dependency injection framework in place? The first link has a solution with CDI, similar solutions would apply for other DI containers.

#### Connection pooling

Application servers offer DB connection pooling. Tomcat does too. Application servers might allow you to add DB connection pools at runtime without the need to restart the server. I do not know if the version of Tomcat you are using supports it (I would guess not, but please correct me). So:

- If the application server (Tomcat in this case) *supports* runtime connection pool creation, do that and tweak the `props` to use it
- Otherwise you will have to use a custom connection pool that applies to each `EntityManagerFactory`. Hibernate at least seems to have this [feature](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-database-connection).

#### Persist the settings

I guess you already have figured this out, but the settings applied at runtime (tenants, tenant name to connection properties mappings) have to be persisted somehow, so that they are reapplied when the server restarts. This could be a configuration file or another "administration" database.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Do you have any experience with the memory consumption of this approach? Currently there are about 1000 customers, which means I have to cache 1000 `EntityManagerFactory` instances and 1000 DB connection pools. Another Question: For the DB connection pools I can use the JNDI, is that correct?

Comment: Woa, 1000 customers! Good for your business :) but you are rightfully concerned: the above may not be the appropriate approach for your case! There could be ways of working around the limitations, but it is highly dependent on the exact workload of you app. E.g. you could keep the EMFs in a size-limited, most recently used cache, or tweak the caching characteristics of the JPA implementation. Or think of a totally different approach. To conclude, I would: (1) consider this AND the alternatives (2) make a PoC of the selected solution and test with a simulated, realistic workload.

Comment: As for the JNDI: if you use the application server to create the pools, then, since application servers normally place the connection pools in JNDI, you will actually *have* to use JNDI. Hibernate's native solution is not placing the pool in JNDI (but I am not aware if there is still a way to configure it). But, in the end of the day, you want the connection pool, JNDI is only a means of obtaining it.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot! I will try out your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help in your particular situation, but I set up an environment in which the JDBC connection URL specified in hibernate.cfg.xml

```xml
<property name="connection.url">
    jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Public/UCanHibernate.accdb;newDatabaseVersion=V2010
</property>
```

could be overriden with a Java System property like so:

```java
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .configure(); // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml

// allow tester to specify their own connection URL (via -D JVM argument)
String runtimeUrl = System.getProperty("HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_URL"); 
if (runtimeUrl != null) {
    ssrb.applySetting("hibernate.connection.url", runtimeUrl);
}
```

You would likely get the override information from a different source, but the principle might still apply.