# Can I create multiple Database Connections from one EntityManagerFactory?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I use JPA with Hibernate in my Servlet, which is hosted by Tomcat. 
The database I use is MySQL. 
I do not use JNDI or a Connection Pool.

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="pixxio-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>de.java2enterprise.onlineshop.model.AccessToken</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.88.88:3306/felix1_0"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="felix1_0"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypassword"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is the important code in my Servlet:

```
void doubleDatabaseConnection(PrintWriter out) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pixxio-jpa", null);
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityManager em2 = emf.createEntityManager();
    getDatabaseSessionId(out, em);
    getDatabaseSessionId(out, em2);
    em.close();
    em2.close();
    emf.close();
}

void getDatabaseSessionId(PrintWriter out, EntityManager entityManager) {
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT CONNECTION_ID();");
    BigInteger result = (BigInteger) q.getSingleResult();

    out.println("<br>Database Session Id: " + result);
}
```

This is printed by the servlet:

```
Database Session Id: 51317
Database Session Id: 51317
```

I assumed that the actual database connection is established, when the EntityManager is created. Therefore I assumed that the two MySQL-Connection-IDs from the two EntityManager instances differ.

Is it possible to create multiple distinct database connections from one EntityManagerFactory instance?

I want to note that changing the JPA provider is an option for me.

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: I am refactoring a SaaS Software with many Customers, each have their own database. I would like to cache the EntityManagerFactory instances for each customer, but I don't want to use Connection Pooling. Instead I would like to create a new Database Connection with the cached EntityManagerFactory for each request.

Comment: Each customer should have their own connection to the database? If I am not mistaken, as soon as a new customer uses that application, it should create a new connection to the database, one which is not in use by other customers

Comment: I think you did not understand, what I want to achieve. Maybe this earlier post of mine makes it more clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349608/can-i-use-jpa-by-specifing-the-database-during-runtime

Comment: Any particular reason you don't *want* to use connection pool?

Comment: We have about 1000 Customers, which means we have 1000 databases. I would assume I run into memory problems when I have 1000 Connection Pools on my server. Furthermore we have the requirement to add new databases (and therefore new Connection Pools) during the runtime of the webcontainer. I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Each EM will have its own datastore connection. End of.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you want to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate use the same connection if you do not need a transaction.

If you start a transation, you get a new connection

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pixxio-jpa", null);

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
EntityManager em2 = emf.createEntityManager();
em2.getTransaction().begin();
getDatabaseSessionId(System.out, em);
getDatabaseSessionId(System.out, em2);
em.close();
em2.close();
emf.close();
```

**Updated**

FYI: Hibernate use it's own connection pool if you do not set an connection pool (min=1; max=20).

Comment: Thank you it works just fine! What happens when I establish a DB connection to another database by overriding the properties in `persistence.xml` (`EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pixxio-jpa", newPropertiesWithNewUrl);`? Does Hibernate create a connection pool for the new database during runtime?

Comment: Sorry for that late answer. You cannot change the connection properties with `createEntityManager`. Please have a look at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#setup-configuration-bootstrapping (section 2.2.2) and the referred section 2.2.1. Therefor - no, there is only one connection pool per persistence unit (`EntityManagerFactory`)